# JQuery Mobile RSS or Atom Feed

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I am looking for some sample code on how to create an RSS or Atom reader in JQuery Mobile like this one http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-build-an-rss-reader-with-jquery-mobile-2/  ... BUT I need the list with added thumbnails on the left.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/docs/lists/index.html

should be enough

[edit]

Ok, tutorial:

1. Go to http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/docs/lists/lists-thumbnails.html
2. rightclick
3. select view source
4. copy and use the code

Comment: I can't find the feed. Can you guide me please?

Comment: There is no feed. You want thumbnails on the left. On the page I linked to there's an element called `thumbnails` and when you click it, you open an example showing how the thumbnails are done.